# Exponentiation of Dedekind cardinals

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, cardinal-arithmetic

**Question:** Let $\mathfrak n$ be an infinite cardinal. In ZF (set theory without the axiom of choice) can either of the implications
$$\mathfrak n=\mathfrak n+1\implies2^\mathfrak n=2^{\mathfrak n+1}\implies2^\mathfrak n=2^\mathfrak n+1$$
be reversed? Equivalently, can either of the implications
$$\mathfrak n\ge\aleph_0\implies2^\mathfrak n=2^{\mathfrak n+1}\implies2^\mathfrak n\ge\aleph_0$$
be reversed?

**Motivation:** Idle curiosity.

**What I know:** The implications can't both be reversed because, if $\mathfrak n=2^\mathfrak m$ is incomparable with $\aleph_0$ (*i.e.*, $2^\mathfrak m$ is a Dedekind-finite infinite cardinal) then $2^\mathfrak m\lt2^\mathfrak m+1$, while $2^{2^\mathfrak m}=2^{2^\mathfrak m}+1$ since $2^{2^\mathfrak m}\ge\aleph_0$ (Russell's theorem).

**Question:** Is $2^{2^\mathfrak m}=2^{2^\mathfrak m+1}$ if $2^\mathfrak m$ is incomparable with $\aleph_0$?

Comment: I think it should be enough that $\aleph_0\leq^*\frak m$, in which case the answer is positive, as any infinite power set maps onto $\omega$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first question, the two implications fail to reverse. For the first implication, just take $\mathfrak{n}$ to be a dually Dedekind infinite, Dedekind finite cardinal. For the second implication, see Theorem 3.5 of the paper *Definitions of finite and the power set operation* by Howard and Spišiak (which is not published, see [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ED9V0eRrwmeY3ckRU0FJZbbxO9DNOs7w/view?usp=sharing) for a copy).

For the second question, the answer is yes. See the paper *Ein Beitrag zur Kardinalzahlarithmetik ohne Auswahlaxiom* by Läuchli; for an English version, see Theorem 5.28 of the book *Combinatorial Set Theory: With a Gentle Introduction to Forcing* (second edition) by Halbeisen.

The key question in this field (proposed by Läuchli) is whether it is provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $2^{2^{\mathfrak{n+1}}}=2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}$ (or equivalently, $(2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}})^2=2^{2^{\mathfrak{n}}}$) for all infinite cardinals $\mathfrak{n}$. I conjecture the answer is no.

Comment: @bof $\mathfrak{n}$ is called dually Dedekind infinite if $\mathfrak{n}+1\leq^\ast\mathfrak{n}$, which is strictly stronger than $\aleph_0\leq^\ast\mathfrak{n}$.

Answer (score 6):

ZF doesn't prove that the first implication reverses; i.e. it doesn't prove that $2^{\mathfrak{n}}=2^{\mathfrak{n}+1}\Longrightarrow \mathfrak{n}\geq\aleph_0$. For suppose $X$ is a set which is the disjoint union of an $\omega$-sequence $\left<p_n\right>_{n<\omega}$ of (unordered) pairs $p_n$, and there is no infinite subset of $X$ which meets each pair in at most one element. Let $\mathfrak{n}=|X|$. Then $\aleph_0\not\leq\mathfrak{n}$. But $2^{\mathfrak{n}}=2^{\mathfrak{n}+1}$. For we can define an injective function $\pi:\mathcal{P}(X)\times 2\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ as follows.

Let $A\subseteq X$. We define $\pi(A,0)$ and $\pi(A,1)$.

Suppose first $A$ is infinite. Then there is some $n<\omega$ such that for all $m\in[n,\omega)$, if $A\cap p_m\neq\emptyset$ then $p_m\subseteq A$. Let $n_A$ be the least such $n$. Let $$P_A=\{i\in\omega\bigm|i> n_A\wedge p_i\subseteq A\}$$. Let $$A'=(A\cap \bigcup_{i\leq n_A}p_i)\cup \bigcup_{i\in P_A}p_{i+1}$$. Now define $$\pi(A,0)=A'$$
and
$$\pi(A,1)=A'\cup p_{n_A+1}.$$

Now suppose $A$ is finite. Let $m_A$ be the least $m\in\omega$ such that $A\subseteq\bigcup_{i<m}p_i$. (So for example, $A\cap p_{m_A}=\emptyset$.) Now let
$$\pi(A,0)=A\cup p_{m_A+1}$$
and
$$\pi(A,1)=A\cup p_{m_A+1}\cup p_{m_A+2}.$$

It is straightforward to check that $\pi$ is injective. So we have $|\mathcal{P}(X)\times 2|\leq\mathcal{P}(X)$, so $2^{\mathfrak{n}}=2^{\mathfrak{n}+1}$.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Note that if $\frak m\leq^* n$, then $2^\mathfrak m\leq 2^\mathfrak n$, since given a surjection from $N$ onto $M$, the preimages define an injection between the power sets. So, if $\frak m\leq^* n\leq^* m$, then $2^\mathfrak m=2^\mathfrak n$.

In particular, if there is a Dedekind-finite infinite cardinal, then there is one for which $1+\frak m\leq^* m$. Therefore, if there are any Dedekind-finite cardinals, then the first implication fails to reverse.

Interestingly, $\aleph_0\leq^*\frak m$ is a weaker condition than $1+\frak m\leq^*m$ (so the former does not imply the latter).

Comment: You left as an exercise the construction of $\mathfrak m$ such that $1+\mathfrak m\le^*\mathfrak m\lt1+\mathfrak m$. I guess one way to do this is to take a Dedekind-finite infinite set $X$ and let $\mathfrak m$ be the cardinality of the set of all non-null finite sequences of distinct elements of $X$.

Comment: Indeed, that is one way of finding such $X$.